# fixed image not showing in Chrome or MS Edge

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a site that displays a Carousel, however as part of the effect the images are fixed so when you scroll down, the image is fixed in the background. Its a hybrid Carousel/Parallax effect. The problem I am facing is that it works great in Firefox but Chrome and MS Edge do not show any images?

I have been using `height: 100vh;` to set the height of the Carousel.

IE seems to show the image however it is abit buggy. Can anyone explain what is happening and a possible fix?

Comment: Hey Garrith, in the future, please include some code to reproduce the issue in your questions, otherwise they risk being closed, which can impact your account negatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers handle the height of positioned elements differently than others.  Just add `height: 100%;` to `.carousel-inner`

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* added */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @GarrithGraham.  Please refrain from making answer changing edits in the future.  `position:fixed` may be required, but it is a separate issue from not seeing the images.  I will leave it in place, but that kind of an edit goes beyond the scope of what the edit feature is for.  Please simply provide a comment instead of changing an answer directly.

Comment: Thanks I will do. You can change it back if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its not working because i have used it in my edge browser but still if you want a change then remove `height:100vh;` its not a finest way to show a full height width if the position is fixed it will also fine with `height:100%`.

Try once!

Comment: vh is the new HTML5 standard is it not?

Comment: Yes it is but you should have also know that new things don't run on all browsers and MS is one of them so sometimes we have to use some old ways to let it work fine...try using height:100% in image css it will work perfectly fine...checked by me :)